# Getting the trigger element for jQuery mobile popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a simple jQuery Mobile popup like this:

```html
<section data-role="popup" data-overlay-theme="a" id="eat">
    Are you sure you want to eat?
</section>
```

And I have multiple links triggering the same popup:

```html
<a href='#eat' data-role='button' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-food="pizza">Pizza</a>
<a href='#eat' data-role='button' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-food="sandwich">Sandwich</a>
```

I'm wondering if there's any way I can determine which link was clicked to open the popup. I have tried:

```js
$('#eat').on('popupafteropen', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

But the console output I have received doesn't give me any object for the trigger element (unless I'm missing something). Is there a way to do this?

**Additional information:** I'm trying to populate something else with the value of the  data-food attribute on the link. Therefore I need a reference to the `<a>` element, not the `<section>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an id for each link

```
     <a href='#eat' id="pizza"    data-role='button' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-food="pizza">Pizza</a>
     <a href='#eat' id="sandwich" data-role='button' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-food="sandwich">Sandwich</a>
```

and used this script

```
<script>
  $('#pizza').on( "click", function() {
    console.log(this);
  });

  $('#sandwich').on( "click", function() {
    console.log(this);
  });
</script>
```

to get it working, see also [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Quxfu/)

console after clicking "Pizza"
[image]

Comment: It had never occurred to me to bind to the trigger element! Thanks, and accepted.
To add to what you had said, this solution will work but it would be impractical for me to add `id`s to the links as these are dynamically retrieved, however it works if I do:

`$('a[data-food]').bind('click', function() { console.log(this); });` .

I guess I should be using `on` though, since `bind` is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you... that's a nice flexible solution now. Somehow I'm always confused which one is deprecated and which one not...;-) answer now updated...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#eat').on('popupafteropen', function(event) {
    console.log(this); // should give you the anchor element
    console.log($(this)); // should give you the jquery anchor element 
});
```

you can also say `event.target` to get the dom element.

Comment: That only gives me the `<section>` element and jQuery section element respectively, not the anchor element.